We are able to have many automation sub tracks per track one for each track that you want to automate what's meaning?
We are able to have many automation sub tracks per track one for each track that you want to automate what's meaning?

You can automate many things on one audio track, such as volume, pan, mute, not to mention every parameter in every plugin. Why do you think one automation track would be enough?

One for each parameter* that you want to automate?  And do you know what automation means?
